# Why do fonts appear jagged in Chrome?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, fonts

My fonts seem to appear really jagged and and hard to read in chrome, how can I make them appear smooth? They didn't used to be like this.

Comment: Every month or so, it happens to me, and after trying everything I could find online, I just gave up on discovering the issue and now I do chrome://flags and reset everything to default. But it always sneaks back in sometime in the future - makes me wonder if Google actually cares about fixing it, since it's been like this for years.

Comment: I never have any issues with it on my home PC, but it happened all the time at work at my old job.  I suspect the IT department was pushing a group policy setting or update that reverts the fix.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In windows 10:

- Go to the windows search, search for "This PC" right click and choose properties
- Go to advanced system settings
- Click the settings button in the performance group
- Check the box for "Smooth edges of screen fonts"
- Restart computer and your fonts will be back to normal

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why mine turned off when windows 10 updated.

Comment: Actually, I think restarting the computer is what fixed this.  At least it does for me.  I've never messed with the checkbox and everything is usually fine again after a reboot.

Comment: had to restart chrome after this

Answer (score 61):

The solution that worked for me was

1. Visit URL  chrome://flags/
2. Enable "Disable accelerated 2D Canvas" (Now called 'Accelerated 2D canvas', If Enabled, set to Disabled)
3. relaunch

Comment: Might be the change of any flag? I changed it to enabled, and it worked. Then changed it to disabled, and everything was still smooth. So next time the issue appears(after next RDP-session), I will test changing another random setting.

Comment: A better (and effective) solution for me with current versions as at posting.  I already have OS font smoothing turned on and every application is smoothed except Chrome.  So it's Chrome, not Windows.
I also do not have the enable-font-cache-scaling flag option.  Either it is no longer supported or invalid for my installation.

Answer (score 19):

try going here: chrome://flags/#enable-font-cache-scaling 
either disable or enable this setting (enable-font-cache-scaling) to see if it changes.
Chrome seems to suddenly get jagged text inexplicably and this fixed it for me.

Comment: worked for me - clicked RESET to DEFAULT - after chrome restarted and all got fixed

Comment: This seems to work as a fix - I set to "Enabled", relaunched Chrome, then flipped it back to "Default" and it remained OK. I find it usually happens after I have used an RDP session to my PC.

Comment: Fixed my issue, Issue occurred immediately after login to local machine after using an RDP session into the same machine. Not sure why the issue occurs but glad it's fixed.

Comment: I saw this issue after our company service desk reset a number of browser related settings. The above and flipping back to default worked for me. The windows option did not.

Answer (score 7):

Another possible cause:

**Remote Desktop** (aka RDC, MSTSC) can disable text smoothing per application.

If you are remotely connected to the machine with the font smoothing problem, and other remote applications are working normally, then this should fix it:

1. Disconnect, and re-open the Remote Desktop Connection window.
2. Click *Show Options*.
3. Click the *Experience* tab.
4. Choose any setting except "Detect connection quality automatically" in the "Choose your connection speed..." listbox.
5. Check the boxes as appropriate, making sure "Font smoothing" is checked.

Also note, after a remote connection triggers this problem, you may still see the ugly fonts on the computer locally until you restart Chrome (or Windows).

Comment: Restarting the PC or Chrome wasn't enough for me.  I had to next do what Chris suggested in his answer

Answer (score 6):

This issue happened to me after a remote RDP session into the workstation.
Resolved using the following:

- Opened page chrome://flags/#enable-font-cache-scaling
- Clicked *Reset all*
- Relaunched Chrome (It also worked in the Microsoft Edge)

After this, the fonts were reset back to the normal view.

Comment: This also resolved the issue for me I found that had affected Obsidian (I guess it uses the same Chrome program installed locally?.. or perhaps it is a setting that RDP messes with since I jump into this machine). Either way, clicking Reset all was the fix for me

Comment: Worked for me as well, but only after I first rebooted the PC.  Great solution. Sometimes when you connect with RDP on a slower connection, RDC client automatically adjusts your graphics settings to lower values and it appears something about this change persisted long after the RDC session had been killed

Answer (score 2):

Turning on hardware acceleration worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

This new Chrome extension helped me: **Chrome Font Super Enhancer** (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-font-super-enhance/ombebcdhklmmkcddekoplmobafpkolmd)

Characters are definitely more readable, and it works with all websites I visited so far.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is:

1. Open Chrome
2. Go to Settings > System
3. Toggle 'Use hardware acceleration when available' once. Regardless of its current position (by default, it should be on 'enabled' position)
4. Relaunch Chrome.

This should solve the issue. *[Just in case you want, go back to same settings & revert the toggle back the switch again & relaunch. It makes no difference.]*

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution when I was above to do what gvb recommended:

1. Visit URL chrome://flags/
2. Enable Override software rendering list and enables GPU-acceleration on unsupported system configurations

Do note the big red letters as the top:  WARNING! EXPERIMENTAL FEATURES AHEAD.  I'm gathering though that something about my system isn't supported, but this worked anyhow.

Comment: chrome://flags/#ignore-gpu-blocklist , then.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing helped at this point, maybe the issue is not Chrome itself. I've discovered that in AMD's Adrenalin the "Radeon Image Sharpening" was enabled. I've switched it off (Gear button -> Graphics), and now the fonts look much better.

Answer (score 0):

I purchased a new laptop and noticed my fonts in my browser looked terribly bad.
What worked was turning off hardware acceleration in the browser (requires browser restart for chromium based browsers).

The reason was that my laptop's graphics card renders fonts poorly for whatever reason. But the built in intel graphics renders text crisp and clearly.

Answer (score 0):

from chrome://flags/ I disabled:

**Font Access APIs** Enables the experimental Font Access APIs, giving websites access to enumerate local fonts and access their table data. – Mac, Windows, Linux, ChromeOS, Fuchsia, Lacros #font-access

Answer (score 0):

What worked in my case was disabling chrome://flags/#enable-fontations-backend.

> If enabled, the Fontations font backend will be used for web fonts
> where otherwise FreeType would have been used. – Mac, Windows, Linux,
> ChromeOS, Android, Fuchsia, Lacros

Windows 11 accessed via RDC.  Nothing else helped much.

Answer (score -1):

You will probably get all kind of pointless "adjust cleartype" ideas, but in general I would do a clean uninstall of GPU drivers, reinstall and possibly reinstall Chrome as well. More often than not there is a problem with your display drivers.

Answer (score -1):

Disabling / re-enabling all the extensions worked for me. For version 66.0.3359.181 (Official Build) (64-bit), on Windows 10, here are the steps I used:

1. Go Chrome menu
2. Select "More Tools"
3. Select "Extensions"
4. Disable all the extensions
5. Close the page
6. Shut down Chrome
7. Re-start Chrome. Fonts now worked
8. Run steps 1-3.
9. This time, enable all the extensions
10. Run steps 5-7. Fonts still work

If the above don't work, follow the steps above, but enable one extension at a time. I needed to restart the browser to see the effects.

My machine config:

1. Chrome version: 66.0.3359.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)
2. OS: Windows 10 Pro