# How to prevent large fonts from looking jagged in Chrome (OSX)?

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, cross-browser

Regular fonts look normal, but large fonts look jagged in Chrome (not in Safari or Firefox). I'm using a Macbook Pro running Mojave.

Example [codepen](https://codepen.io/nachocab/pen/qwjojW)

```
.large {
  font-size: 300px
  font-weight: bold
}
```

**Chrome**

[image]

**Safari**

[image]

**Firefox**

[image]

I've tried the recommendations in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46535842/why-do-fonts-appear-jagged-in-chrome) (enable-font-cache-scaling and accelerated 2D Canvas), but the issue remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning chrome://settings "Use hardware acceleration when available" *OFF* fixed it for me.

At first I was not able to reproduce the jagginess/blockiness, but I realized I was looking at it on MacOS [High] Sierra, and you specified Mojave. So I tried it there, and it is absolutely awful. I'm really surprised this escaped anyone's notice in testing. I'd imagine there will be an update to either Chrome or Mojave that addresses this soon.

I guess this is actually related to a change to the OS defaults; Apple apparently [disabled sub-pixel font rendering in Mojave and passed it off as a "refinement"](https://angristan.xyz/how-to-fix-font-rendering-macos-10-14-mojave/). Sub-pixel rendering is handled by the GPU, hence disabling GPU rendering in Chrome "fixes" it. I guess you could also use the `defaults write` technique specified in the link I mentioned.

In any case: this is probably *not* something you can address in your CSS code, since it is related to user-local/machine settings.

Comment: Thank you so much! You hit the nail on the head!